# Is it allowed to POST empty data?

Tags: php, apache, http, post, http-post

For a web API I'm developing I want to do something similar to Facebook Graph API. A user can invite another user. To accept or reject the invitation, the other user needs to do an empty POST to:

```
/invitation/<invitationId>/accepted
```

or

```
/invitation/<invitationId>/rejected
```

However, this is not working for me as, when I POST empty data, PHP (or Apache?) returns the following error:

> Request entity too large!
>
> The POST
>   method does not allow the data transmitted, or the data volume
>   exceeds the capacity limit.

Obviously this is not true since the POST data is empty (I double-checked in Firebug). So my questions are:

- Does the HTTP protocol allow POSTing empty data? If it doesn't I guess I'll just post some dummy data but I'd rather avoid this kind of hack.
- If it *is* allowed, how can I make Apache/PHP allow the request?

Comment: Why do you POST at all and just not link to that page? If you need `form action=""` and `<button>` for navigation why not just use `method="get"`?

Comment: Yes, it's allowed to send an empty $_POST, but, Does it make sense to do that?

Comment: Why not implement the API as a GET request? it might prove easier to use from javascript with JSONP for example and if you do not need to send any data, GET is the way to go.

Comment: I don't agree with @Yaniro as it's generally considered best practice for GET to do read-only operations and only do operations that cause a change with POST (It's not set in stone of course, but that's the recommended best practice, because you want to be able to bookmark or share a link to the result of a GET).  If posting nothing is causing an error, then maybe you can work around it by just giving your submit control a name so that it's posted as a form value, which you can then just ignore serverside.  Just because data was posted doesn't mean you have to use it for anything.

Comment: I don't agree with @GordonM because we're talking about an API, not a link to a page which might be bookmarked.  If no data needs to be sent as part of the request GET is a good way to go.

Comment: Agreed with yaniro. GET should be ok in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you want to do some kind of a RESTful api, and that's why you need to send post with no data.

Apache/php should allow you to send empty post data, the restrictions must be imposed by some server configurations of the framework you are using

you can test this with this simple file:

```
<?php

echo '<h2>This page was requested using ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] . '</h2>';
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Request this page using POST" />
</form>
```

You will see that the script detects the post request (using REQUEST_METHOD from the _SERVER superglobal) even if the _POST array is empy

Answer (score -1):

Why are you doing a POST request? Make your API detect if data is sent or not and if there is no data, then make a GET request. In fact, make a GET request in most cases as it is far more efficient, since browser can cache that information more easily (and you can make your API smart to take advantage of that by sending cache-specific headers).

There's no point making a POST request in your case :)

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't really answer the question. I think like @GordonM above that GET queries shouldn't modify anything in the system. Moreover, I don't want the request to be cached since it modifies data. I completely see your point though but that's not really the question. Let's assume I have a good reason to send an empty POST data :) The question is: can it be done? and if so, why PHP is rejecting the request?